# Using knitr to create HTML slides and separate R code file

Tags: r, markdown, knitr

Following on from this [question](http://Using%20knitr%20to%20create%20HTML%20slide%20with%20separate%20output%20of%20just%20the%20R%20code)... I am not sure where to set knitr option if I want to output a separate file of R code. The following does not provide the expected additional .R files in my working directory.

````
---
output: ioslides_presentation
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library("knitr"); purl("myfile.rmd")
#library("knitr"); knit("test_tangle.Rmd", tangle = TRUE)
#opts_knit$set(tangle=TRUE)
```

## Slide with Plot
```{r, echo=TRUE}
plot(cars)
```
````

but an error message...

```
Quitting from lines 6-7 (myfile.rmd) 
Error in readLines(if (is.character(input2)) { : 
  cannot open the connection
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withVisible -> eval -> eval -> purl -> knit ->     readLines
Execution halted
```

Comment: have you tried `library("knitr"); purl("myfile.rmd")` ?

Comment: `knit("test_tangle.Rmd", tangle = TRUE)` works for me.

Comment: @BenBolker  Both suggestions give an error message? I created the file using File | New File | R Markdown... | Presentation and then did a Save As before hitting the Knit HTML button

Comment: I think @RomanLuštrik and I are both suggesting that you try running our commands from the console.

Comment: @BenBolker. I see, I was fixated on trying to do it within the .Rmd file and hence oblivious to your approaches. Many thanks.

Comment: It's stil la .Rmd file, but you have to run it from R. I don't think Rstudio provides a button for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use the `hook_purl` function instead. The function `purl()` (or equivalently, `knit(tangle = TRUE)`) may fail to work in certain cases, and the hook function `hook_purl()` is more reliable. See `?hook_purl` for more information.

````
---
output: ioslides_presentation
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library("knitr")
knit_hooks$set(purl = hook_purl)
```

## Slide with Plot
```{r, echo=TRUE}
plot(cars)
```
````

Then as you knit the document, the R script will be automatically generated.

Comment: Thanks @Yihui. Just what I wanted. Awesome!